# ICMPv6: NA: <MAC address> advertised our address <IPv6 address> on <iface>!

Tags: raspbian, ipv6

I have a Pi Zero W running Raspbian 11. It is connected via WiFi. I am using dhcpcd to configure my interfaces (the official method IIUC) with the default config file. I have a DHCPv4 and v6 server available. SLAAC should also work.

I get messages every 5-10s along the lines of:

```
kernel: ICMPv6: NA: <MAC address> advertised our address <IPv6 address> on <iface>!
```

IIUC that normally means there is an IPv6 address conflict but in this case the MAC address is for the Pi's wlan0 interface and the IPv6 address is the IPv6 address for that interface. So something on the Pi is presumably seeing these NAs and the kernel thinks they come from someone else?

Who is supposed to be responsible for sending NAs under Raspbian? The kernel or a process?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't much of an answer but I disabled dhcpcd and used systemd-networkd instead and the problem has gone away. I guess dhcpcd might have been sending NAs but left the kernel NA support enabled?

For people in the same boat there is a quick guide my @Millways to do the same here: [How do I set up networking/WiFi/static IP address on Raspbian/Raspberry Pi OS?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address-on-raspbian-raspberry-pi-os/117843#117843). I didn't follow it exactly but that was the jist.